# Unable to get correct date format in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I am trying to change date format but its showing me wrong result (showing me 1970-01-01),How can i fix this, i want dynamic date in "Y-m-d" format,Here is my code

```
$start_date2=$_POST['start_date']; //showing 10-30-2022
echo $new_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date2)); // showing 1970-01-01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upcoming date format in `$start_date2=$_POST['start_date'];` is incorrect that's why you are getting an incorrect result

So you need to first correct its format and then try to change its format to your desired one. check the code below

```
<?php

$start_date2='10-30-2022'; //date format inccorect
$start_date2=str_replace('-','/',$start_date2); // correct date format
echo $new_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date2)); // now you will get correct result
```

https://3v4l.org/dQHHA

Reference : [PHP Date Formats](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

**Important Note:** try to change the date field format in your HTML form itself if possible, then you can directly do : `$new_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date2));`

Answer (score 0):

If the POST value is "showing 10-30-2022", you are doing something very wrong.

When you have a date field in a form it should look like:

```
<input type="date" name="start_date" />
```

The above will post a date value in the format of 'Y-m-d'.

That makes your `date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_date2));` superfluous.